# Angular directive to capitalize letters and ignore numbers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following Angular directive that should capitalize the input and also reject any characters that are not English alphabet characters:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" capitalize />


.directive('capitalize', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
        if (inputValue == undefined) inputValue = '';

        inputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, ''); //to reject non-alphabet characters
        var capitalized = inputValue.toUpperCase();
        if (capitalized !== inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return capitalized;
      }
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
      capitalize(scope[attrs.ngModel]); // capitalize initial value
    }
  };
})
```

It does capitalize the input, but does NOT reject non-alphabet characters. Suggestions?

Comment: I dropped your code into a fiddle and it does work. The model is not updated if you don't enter the correct information: http://jsfiddle.net/p149wuL1/

Comment: Correct the model is not updated but how can I prevent the text input from accepting improper characters at all?

Comment: You could look into angular-ui-mask to see if it does what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your updated input value after removing special charters in a separate variable, and then capitalize it, so that the capitalized updated input value can be compared from the original value.

```
 var charString = inputValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, ''); //to reject non-alphabet characters
 var capitalized = charString.toUpperCase();
```

updated JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/p149wuL1/3/
I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common idea - lets allow only some special characters in input. (Only letters in your case) And it looks attractive for a while.

Unfortunately, there is no easy solution. It seems there is no user-friendly solution at all. Remember that there are 3 principal ways of input into text field:
1. Keyboard
2. Copy-paste
3. Drag-drop

If 1st way can be reasonably well handled, what about 2nd and 3rd? What should paste of '123%^$ R, A' result in your case? What should be result of paste '123'? Nothing?

Add here some tricks to keep carret position...

To sum, I kindly advice you to let text field to be text field and just mark input as invalid if there is wrong character.

Comment: If the directive can change a 'c' to a 'C' why can't it change a  '2' to '' ?

Comment: because when you paste 123 and see no change -- this looks like nothing works, also because it changes size of text - pasting 'a1b' to field with max-length='2' result in a1, transform to A1 is harmless, transform to 1 is strange. Try to find such controls on i.e. google sites.